# In a CMD batch script, how do I remove an element from an array after finding and assigning it to a variable?

Tags: arrays, batch-file

I'm trying to assign unused drive letters to variables, each time removing the one virtually assigned.
Here's an example:

```
@echo off
set "DriveArray=c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"
            
for %%S in (%DriveArray%) do (if not exist %%S:\ set SYS=%%S)
::TODO Remove the letter assigned to %SYS% from the array.
            
for %%D in (%DriveArray%) do (if not exist %%D:\ set DATA=%%D)
::TODO Remove the letter assigned to %DATA% from the array.
        
set SYS=%SYS%:
set DATA=%DATA%:

echo DriveArray after assignments is %DriveArray%
echo SYS is set to %SYS% 
echo DATA is set to %DATA%
```

Comment: You can read about string replacement by opening up a command prompt and typing: `set /?` to read the help file for the command.

Comment: You could use `setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion & set "DriveArray=C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z " & (for /F "skip=1 delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LOGICALDISK GET DeviceID 2^>nul') do set "DriveArray=!DriveArray:%%I =!") & set DriveArray & endlocal`. Run in a cmd window `setlocal /?`, `endlocal /?`, `set /?`, `for /?`, `wmic /?`, `wmic logicaldisk /?`, `wmic logicaldisk get /?` and read each output help carefully and completely and run finally `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LOGICALDISK GET DeviceID` to see processed data.

Comment: Run also in command prompt window `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LOGICALDISK GET >"%UserProfile%\Documents\LogicalDiskData.txt" & %SystemRoot%\Notepad.exe "%UserProfile%\Documents\LogicalDiskData.txt"` and see the full data provided by the [Win32_LogicalDisk class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk) output by __WMIC__ in Unicode using UTF-16 Little Endian encoding with byte order mark (BOM).

Comment: Alternatively: As the cmd.exe batch script "language" (I use the term loosely) doesn't really support arrays, I would suggest switching to PowerShell which supports arrays, hashtables, objects, and much more. (It is far superior in nearly every conceivable way.)

Comment: First of all, this is not an array but a simple string. Anyway, to remove a drive letter, do something like `call set "DriveArray=%%DriveArray: %%S = %%`, given that you include a leading space and a trailing one into the original string…

Answer (score 0):

After going through the suggestions, I came up with a solution that works.
To re-iterate, I'm virtually assigning unused drive letters to variables. You can use these variables later on for a **diskpart /s script_file** to actually assign those drive letters.
NOTE: I'm deliberately starting from the end of the alphabet, as this suits my purposes.
Bonus tip 1: The command **FSUTIL FSINFO DRIVES** can also display currently used drive letters.
Bonus tip 2: The command (in CMD) **powershell "Get-CimInstance CIM_LogicalDisk | select DeviceID"** can also display currently used drive letters.
So here's the working solution:

```
@echo off
::===========DELAYED EXPANSION NOW ENABLED============================
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "DriveArray= Z Y X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C "

:: The following code will remove occupied drive letters from DriveArray
for /F "skip=1 delims=:" %%M in ('wmic LOGICALDISK GET DeviceID 2^>nul') do (set "DriveArray=!DriveArray: %%M = !")

echo Available drive letters for assignment:
echo %DriveArray%
echo[

for /f "delims= " %%S in ('echo %DriveArray%') do (
 set SYS=%%S
 goto :AfterSettingSYS
)

:AfterSettingSYS
echo SYS has been assigned drive letter %SYS%
echo[
set "DriveArray=!DriveArray: %SYS% = !"
echo Remaining drive letters for assignment:
echo %DriveArray%

for /f "delims= " %%T in ('echo %DriveArray%') do (
 set DATA=%%T
 goto :AfterSettingDATA
)
:AfterSettingDATA
set "DriveArray=!DriveArray: %DATA% = !"
echo[

echo DATA has been assigned drive letter %DATA%
echo[
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
::===========DELAYED EXPANSION NOW DISABLED============================
:: If you wish to add a colon sign to drive letters, do so after DiskPart, 
:: as the assign command requires only the drive letter.
set SYS=%SYS%:
set DATA=%DATA%:
echo SYS is set to %SYS% 
echo DATA is set to %DATA%

pause
```